# Libgdx GWT No index.html file in war folder

Tags: eclipse, gwt, libgdx

So for the past few hours I have been trying to launch my libgdx game in html.  I have gwt installed, and I tried following the instructions on the libgdx wiki, but nothing's working.  I've tried GWT compile, and I've launched it in all the dev modes.  I tried to launch it from a brand new project all the same ways but still nothing.  I also tried setting the the WAR directory to webapp and war.  When I use webapp I get a link in the eclipse Development Mode tab and when I open it I get a 404 index.html not found, but when I use war its blank.  When I check the war folder there is not an index.html no matter how many times I compile the project (although it does have my assets, WEB-INF, and a html folder).  There is one in webapp so I tried moving it to the war folder. I get a link but again I get a 404 index.html not found.  I have no idea what's going on.  I've been searching around on google and nothing seems to be working.  I'm not sure what I should upload to help, so I'll upload any information you think might help.

Comment: do this project runs in other format? the desktop or the android version?

Comment: yeah. android and desktop work fine.  And I'm testing this on a new empty project now to eliminate error in my own code but still the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

I get this same issue when using the mojo maven gwt plugin when running on macos. This doesn't seems to have issues on Windows.

The fix is to add the flag copyWebapp=true to the pom.xml, so it looks like this:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${gwt.version}</version>
<configuration>
     <strict>true</strict>

     <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
     <mode>htmlunit</mode>
     <includes>**/*GwtTest.java</includes>

     <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>

     <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
     <module>com.kiwlm.pykdo.GwtMaterialBasic</module>
     <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
</configuration>
```

I am not that familiar with how libgdx runs GWT but I think this is most likely it.